# Why "set" method is required when data member is initialized using a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Why do we need set method in most of Java classes when we implicitly initialize data members using a constructor.

```
public class Foo
{

   private int id;

   private String name;

   public Foo(int id, String name)
   {
     this.id=id;
     this.name=name;
   }

   public void setId(int a)
   {
     id=a;
   }

   public int getId()
   {
    return id;
   }

}
```

---

and, say I have an application that instantiates Foo like this:

```
Foo obj1 = new Foo(2, "Example1");
```

Why would I require `setId` in `Foo` class when I have already initialize it during call of constructor? Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: It isn't required. It's a design decision.

Comment: As is the getId(). You could make *name* final as its not changed.

Comment: Who says set is required? I never heard of it. It would actually be better if `id` were immutable, which would dictate no setter.

Answer (score 6):

So you can change the value **after** initialisation.

Answer (score 3):

It allows for the value to be changed from outside the class. Removing the setter would make the field immutable.

Comment: Wouldn't it make one of following lines redundant? this.id=id; or setId(3). I am initializing the Id twice. Once with constructor and once with setmethod.

Comment: The setter doesn't initialize the field, it changes the field. The initialization happens when the class is constructed. If you don't ever need the setter or want to disallow outside world to change the field, then just remove the setter.

Comment: Thank you . I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to change the value after initialization, you don't need to. 
In fact it may be even better not to implement the setter method if the value is not going to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to sell the class to others, who might like to set the value.

Or, you might like to implement some changes in the future, so you would code a set() method now so you don't have to worry about it then.

Or even, the code may have been generated by some sort of automatic code-generation tool which by default includes setters.

To answer the question in the title though, it's not required.  You could take it out and the code would compile just fine.

Comment: The second is a really bad justification for anything in software.  Don't compromise the design today (especially very useful concepts like immutability) just because "someone *might* want to call a setter in future".  Also, do you really mean *sell* in the first line, as opposed to something like *pass instances of*?

Comment: Thank you . I appreciate your answer too.

Comment: I was trying to cover all bases, since a Class Foo could be anything and there was no hint at all as to what type of class we're talking about! There must be people out in the world who make a living from selling java components, right?  And if you're selling your components, then you definitely want to include setters!